# Change file permsission on Android app programmatically

Tags: android, file-permissions

In my Android app, I want to create files preserved in case of app uninstallation.

I can create hidden file in

```
File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), ".SecretFolder")
```

My goal is to change read and write permission for this file.

I tried to uninstall my app -> File is preserved. After installation at reaf time I get AccessDeniedException

Now if I want to change read and write permission using `File.setReadable(true, false)` and `File.setWritable(true, false)`, I can observe no change in Android Device File explorer (remains -rw-------) even if the API return true for both.

Note: I'm using a Virtual Device based on Android 11, API 30. I'm not targetting this version specifically

here is my code:

```
private fun writeFileOnInternalStorage(remainingToken : Int) {
            val dir = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), ".SecretFolder")
            if(!dir.exists()){
                if(dir.mkdirs()){
                    var allowed = dir.setReadable(true, false)
                    println("DBEUG dir ${dir.toPath()} is world-readable ? $allowed")
                    allowed = dir.setWritable(true, false)
                    println("DBEUG dir ${dir.toPath()} is world-writable ? $allowed")
                }else{
                    println("ERROR")
                    return
                }
            }
            val f = File(dir, ".secretFile")
            if(!f.exists()){
               f.createNewFile()
               var allowed = f.setReadable(true, false)
                println("DBEUG ${f.toPath()} is world-readable ? $allowed")
               allowed = f.setWritable(true, false)
                println("DBEUG ${f.toPath()} is world-writable ? $allowed")
            }
            f.writeText(remainingToken.toString())
            println("DEBUG: written Internal Storage \"${remainingToken}\" in " + f.toPath().toString())
        }
```

Comment: After reinstall that file is considered not to belong to your app. You cannot change that.

Comment: Instead use SAF to let the user select the directory or that file.

Comment: If you had created a media file your app would still have access.

Comment: maybe `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` will help for your case, but if you want publish this app in Play Store then you must have a strong argument for handling such "sensitive" permission. also targeting for older API than above restriction were introduced may work, but then to old for publishing in Play Store

Comment: @blackapps what about app update ? my app can still re-use old files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have rights to that file, and so you do not have rights to change the permissions of that file. A file in `Documents/` can only be accessed by the app that created the file, and only for the specific *installation* of that app. Apps that are uninstalled and reinstalled are considered to be independent installations.

(I doubt that technique would work anyway, as Android manages file permissions differently)

Ordinarily, I would steer you to the Storage Access Framework. However, that is designed to do what users want: give them control over the storage. You appear to be attempting to hide your activity from the user ("create hidden file"). Google, device manufacturers, and users are working very hard to prevent developers from doing this.

Comment: Here, I want to "offer" access when creating the file ```f.createNewFile``` so I was thinking I can call setReadable/setWritable right after creation...

I agree with your statement about hidding activities, I may need to find a different way to perform what I want (store tokens)

Comment: @Flochocinco: Those calls will have no effect. The rights for content in `Documents/` is driven by other facets of Android security. "I may need to find a different way to perform what I want (store tokens)" -- store them on your server, associated with a user account. When the user logs in on the new app installation, download the tokens.

Comment: true, but as a single developper with limited knowledge, I didn't want to manage a server with account management (plus RGPD as europeen).
Thank you for advicing me